# Run Java code on my own JVM

Tags: java, security, jvm

In [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515834/best-approach-to-create-a-security-environment-in-java/2516149#2516149), someone say something about run the java code on its own jvm, which ignores SecurityManager.

Is it possible? (and as easy as saying?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You can download a JVM open source implementation, modify it to ignore the security manager and build it. But I think this is not an easy task. This [sun](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5199656) forum may help you

Comment: Yep, and there are also other open source jvm implementations like gcj.

Answer (score 1):

Google "java security policy" for directions on setting up the security policy for your own jvm.  You can change the rules about which classes and methods are restricted.  It doesn't "ignore" the SecurityManager, it allows you to modify the rules.

Comment: but it will not ignore if I implement my own hard coded policy, right? (I mean, by making my SecurityManager and AccessControl).
The final security policy is the intersection of the internal policies and the user's policy file policies.